# Changing Image tool default spacing from 5px to 0px

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, ribbon, image

I-m looking for a way to change the `5px` horizontal/vertical space on the Image ribbon. Anyone know if/how this can be changed?

If the users decides to change the `0px` to `40px` this choice still has to be respected.